# Reset react-select dropdown when new props passed in

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I would like to clear the value in the dropdown on getting new props. Currently, the previous value remains visible even though if I expand the dropdown, I can see new values.

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import axios from 'axios';    

class KeydateDropdown extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            optionList: []
        };
    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        let vesselname = this.props.vesselname;
        if (prevProps.vesselname !== vesselname) {
            let keydateList = [];
            this.setState({
                optionList: keydateList
            });
            axios.get('list-keydates', {
                params: {
                    vesselname: vesselname
                }
            })
                .then((response) => {
                    let data = response.data['intervention'];
                    data.forEach((element) => {
                        keydateList.push({ value: element, label: element });
                    });
                    this.setState({ optionList: keydateList });
                })
        }
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <Select
                isDisabled={this.props.isDisabled}
                onChange={this.props.handleKeydateChange}
                options={this.state.optionList}
                className={styles.dropdown}
            />
        );
    }

}

export default KeydateDropdown;
```

I have confirmed that the first `setState()` inside `componentDidUpdate` which clears  `optionList` calls `render()`

Edit: Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-night-zcu31)

Comment: Could you provide a codesandbox example to make it easier to help you? Also, it looks like you are not setting an explicit value in the `Select` component. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Hi I have added the codesandbox. Please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to explicitly set a value on the `Select` component. You have to pass `this.state.selectedKeydate` to `KeydateDropdown` in `MainInputBar` and then pass that value to the `Select` component:

In `MainInputBar.jsx`:

```
      keydateDropdown = (
        <KeydateDropdown
          vesselname={this.state.selectedVessel.value}
          selectedKeydate={this.state.selectedKeydate}
          handleKeydateChange={this.handleKeydateChange}
          value={this.state.selectedKeydate}
        />
      );
```

In `KeyStateDropdown.jsx`:

```
      <Select
        isDisabled={this.props.isDisabled}
        onChange={this.props.handleKeydateChange}
        options={this.state.optionList}
        className={styles.dropdown}
        value={this.props.value}
      />
```

I forked your sandbox and fixed it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-einstein-55klv

Comment: Thank you! That was it indeed - I didn't get what you were saying the first time.

Comment: If you don't explicitly pass in a value to the `Select` component, it uses an internal state to keep track of it (implicit value). It was a bit hard to explain in a comment, hence the question for the codesandbox. Happy to be able to help you.